# PHP script works from browser but not from Windows Server Task Scheduler or from CMD/PS

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2012-r2, php-7.2, windows-task-scheduler

I have this simple script called `webcam.php` to acquire some screenshot from webcams

```
<?php
    $d=date('YmdHis');
    $url = 'http://xxx:40801/snap.jpeg?'.$d;
    $img = 'camera_east.jpg';
    echo file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));

    $url = 'http://xxx:40802/snap.jpeg?'.$d;
    $img = 'camera_west.jpg';
    echo file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));

    echo $d;
?>
```

and if I call `http://xxx/webcam.php` from browser, everything's OK:
I find the two pictures in the folder, and the script returns the length of the files  and the timestamp as echoes.

I tried to make this script to be executed by the windows scheduler, but although it returns `0x0`  the pictures are not updated.

(I tried also `unlinking` the images, and also using `curl` but nothing changes)

Then I tried to run the PHP script from command line (also from PowerShell):
something like:

```
C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php.exe -f C:\\webcam.php
```

but again, although it seems working, since it returns the length of the two files and the timestamp, the pictures are not updated and if I add `unlink` command, files are not cancelled:

Clearly folder has all permissions...

I've not big experience in PHP... :-(
what can be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

obviously from cmd/ps/scheduler requires the full path, 
while from browser can accept relative path